# GCC ARM Cortex-M3/M4: SVC instruction puts CPU from Thumb to ARM state because of wrong value in Vector table

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, system-calls, thumb

I'm porting real-time kernel [TNeoKernel](https://bitbucket.org/dfrank/tneokernel) to the Cortex-Mx processors, it works when compiled with ARMCC, but doesn't work when compiled with GCC: just after calling `SVC` instruction, `PC` is updated to the `SVC_Handler`, and at the next (any) instruction, UsageFault exception happens.

Examining of `CFSR` shows that `INVSTATE` bit is set: i.e. the processor is in ARM state, which is illegal on Cortex-M CPUs. I've checked `xPSR`: yes, `T` bit is cleared.

Then I've examined Vector table: yes, at the offset `0x2c` I have the address of my `SVC_Handler`, but LSB is cleared: `0x8013c40`. So, there's no surprise that CPU is put to the ARM state. The surprise is why do I have LSB cleared?

I re-checked address of `SVC_Handler` when compiled with ARMCC, and yes, LSB is set there: actual address of `SVC_Handler` is `0x0800297a`, but Vector table contains `0x0800297b`.

So, GCC generates wrong Vector table.

Currently I use CooCox IDE and `arm-none-eabi-gcc` version 4.8.4; options that are given to GCC are:

`-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4`

It seems pretty enough to make GCC know that the CPU does not support ARM state, so, is it a bug in GCC? Or, should I give some more keys to it, to make it generate correct Vector table?

**UPD:** here is the source file [tn_arch_cortex_m.S](https://bitbucket.org/dfrank/tneokernel/src/c505c8ebdfa2326d596dabd5d16947da956821f0/src/arch/cortex_m/tn_arch_cortex_m.S?at=default) on bitbucket. I have `.thumb` directive there; please note that this file is intended to work with GCC as well as ARMCC, so there are some macros to cope for both tools.

Comment: It is always helpful to [point people to the source](https://bitbucket.org/dfrank/tneokernel/src/d1c6620848f6b71759676d79ea99ced5b0e9a8da/src/arch/cortex_m/tn_arch_cortex_m.S?at=default#cl-263).  My guess is that GNU **as** (assembler) has different pseudo-ops and they are not set for the `SVC_Handler`.  Specifically, you need `.thumb` and `.thumb_func` to do this. See: [recent U-boot and Thumb2](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2014-November/195889.html).

Comment: @artlessnoise Sorry for not mentioning the source; I've updated my question. I do use `.thumb` although don't use `.thumb_func`, let me try...

Comment: @artlessnoise Thank you so much, `.thumb_func` does the trick! Holy cow, I've spent so much time. Could you please teach me your gcc-fu a bit: how have you found this information so quickly? I've read The Definitive Guide to ARM Cortex-M3/M4 (before implementing Cortex port), I googled a lot before asking, and I failed to find this. Now that I know about `thumb_func`, I've just re-checked latest pdf from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ , there's nothing about `.thumb_func`! So, how have you found it?

Comment: @artlessnoise please write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing ARM and THUMB instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526062/mixing-arm-and-thumb-instructions) and also [GAS ARM directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html) documentation.

Comment: I have up voted your question.  It is easy to find the answer when you know it :)  However, I think linking it as a duplicate is better for Stack Overflow than answering it for points.